# VBA need to run a macro when any cell in a certain range is updated through a formula

Tags: excel, vba

In my workbook on the sheet "Overview" I have the following calendar.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNRaU.jpg

You can select the check boxes to add a production day. The check boxes are tied to cells on the "Calculations" tab as seen below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1nvr.jpg

The left chart is the output from the checkboxes, and the right chart gets the date from the overview tab if the corresponding chart value is True.

I then have been manually running the following VBA code to collect all the days from the right chart and paste them in a column

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim Index As Long, V As Variant, ArrIn As Variant, ArrOut As Variant
  Const TableRange As String = "S4:Y9"
  Const OutputSheet As String = "Calculations"
  Const OutputStartCell As String = "G2"
  ArrIn = Range(TableRange)
  ReDim ArrOut(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(TableRange)), 1 To 1)
  For Each V In ArrIn
    If Len(V) Then
      Index = Index + 1
      ArrOut(Index, 1) = V
    End If
  Next
  Worksheets(OutputSheet).Range(OutputStartCell).Resize(UBound(ArrOut)) = ArrOut
  Range("G2:G12").Sort key1:=Range("G2:G12"), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

I would like this code to run automatically anytime a cell in the ("S4:Y9") range is updated. I have tried to use the change, and the calculate commands but have been unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I have added the following code, and nothing happens when I click the check boxes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Target.Intersect(Range("S4:Y9")) Is Nothing Then 'The edited range must at         least overlap with S4:Y9'
          Dim Index As Long, V As Variant, ArrIn As Variant, ArrOut As Variant
            Const TableRange As String = "S4:Y9"
            Const OutputSheet As String = "Calculations"
            Const OutputStartCell As String = "G2"
            ArrIn = Range(TableRange)
            ReDim ArrOut(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(TableRange)), 1 To 1)
            For Each V In ArrIn
             If Len(V) Then
                  Index = Index + 1
                  ArrOut(Index, 1) = V
                End If
             Next
            Worksheets(OutputSheet).Range(OutputStartCell).Resize(UBound(ArrOut)) = ArrOut
            Range("G2:G12").Sort key1:=Range("G2:G12"), _
                order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
                End If
End Sub
```

EDIT 2:I am now attempting to assign the macro to all the checkboxes, so anytime a checkbox is changed it will run the macro. THe problem I am running into is, the code was originally written to be on the same worksheet as the calculations. I need to update it to reference the "Calculations" tab. I have tried to use "with" but it isnt working. See new code below.

```
Sub Macro1()
          Dim Index As Long, V As Variant, ArrIn As Variant, ArrOut As Variant
          With Worksheets("Calculations")
            Const TableRange As String = "S4:Y9"
            Const OutputSheet As String = "Calculations"
            Const OutputStartCell As String = "G2"
            ArrIn = Range(TableRange)
            ReDim ArrOut(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(TableRange)), 1 To 1) 'this line is highlighted when the error is displayed
            For Each V In ArrIn
             If Len(V) Then
                  Index = Index + 1
                  ArrOut(Index, 1) = V
                End If
             Next
            Worksheets(OutputSheet).Range(OutputStartCell).Resize(UBound(ArrOut)) = ArrOut
            Range("G2:G12").Sort key1:=Range("G2:G12"), _
                order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

            End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of what you tried with the `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)` Event? I believe that it might not be working, but off the top of my head it seems like that would be the place to do the updating you are describing... (MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: You could assign a macro to your checkboxes, if this is the only way changes are mode to the cells.

Comment: I have eddited the OP

Comment: @Tim Williams: That idea would work. I am unsure how to amend my code to reference the different sheet. Since my code was originally written on the same sheet it was referencing, I will need to add references to the Calculations sheet before all the ranges. I'm not sure of the proper syntax.

Comment: `Thisworkbook.Sheets("Calculations").Range(...)`

Comment: I tried replacing    `Const TableRange As String = "S4:Y9"`
with    `Const TableRange As String = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Calculations").Range("S4:Y9")`
I was given errors

Comment: Updated the OP again to reflect the code I am now trying to tie to all the check boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()

   Const TableRange As String = "S4:Y9"
   Const OutputSheet As String = "Calculations"
   Const OutputStartCell As String = "G2"

   Dim Index As Long, V As Variant, ArrIn As Variant, ArrOut As Variant
   Dim rngTbl as Range

   With Worksheets(OutputSheet)
        Set rngTbl = .Range(TableRange) '<< note dot!
   End With

   ArrIn = rngTbl.Value       
   ReDim ArrOut(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngTbl), 1 To 1)             
   For Each V In ArrIn
       If Len(V) Then
           Index = Index + 1
           ArrOut(Index, 1) = V
       End If
   Next

   Worksheets(OutputSheet).Range(OutputStartCell).Resize(UBound(ArrOut,1)) = ArrOut

   Range("G2:G12").Sort key1:=Range("G2:G12"), _
                order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo



End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I had to modify the sort function at the bottom to reference the worksheet. But it is working perfectly. Thanks Tim, really saved me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Worksheet Change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
    If Not Target.Intersect(Range("S4:Y9")) is Nothing Then 'The edited range must at least overlap with S4:Y9'
        'Your code here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited the OP to reflect your code, it isn't working. Please check and see if I have done something wrong.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` isn't triggered if the change occurs as the result of a formula recalculating.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams, apologies user3638182, behind a firewall that doesn't allow me to see the images.  I was under the impression that the range S4:Y9 was being modified directly.  As Tim points out, cells with recalculated formulas do not trigger the Worksheet_Change event.  If the checkboxes are what change, then I agree with Tim's suggestion that you attach macros to them.